# VIM use system clipboard

Tags: linux, vim

So I'm a real noob to VIM and trying now again to get finally to the level of productivity.

One big problem I have with this editor is, that it uses a clipboard for itself, which I don't understand why.

With VIM I have now 3 clipboards on my system, which is totally unnecessary from my point of view. The global clipboard with CTRL+x, CTRL+c and CTRL+v, the clipboard on mousebutton3 which pastes the last highlighted text and now the VIM clipboard I can use with y and p in VIM.

There are some threads about this topic, but the answers only confuse me more. 
So how do I accomplish, that VIM only uses the global clipboard and the clipboard on mousebutton3?

Some may say that I should use *, but that only goes through the lines and then outputs "search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP" at the bottom. Maybe I don't understand the syntax and the answers suggest me to use a different keystroke before hitting *, but I have no clue about what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://vi.stackexchange.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: No. The right place for Vim questions is SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Maybe I don't understand…

Yes. That seems to be your problem.

Assuming you have a proper Vim installed and `:echo has('clipboard')` returns `1`, you have direct access to your system's two "clipboards" via their associated registers:

- *PRIMARY* (middle mouse button), via `"*`,
- *CLIPBOARD* (Ctrl+c, Ctrl+x, Ctrl+v), via `"+`.

You are supposed to press `"`, followed by `*` or `+`, followed by `y` or `p`.

If you want to yank something in Vim and paste it in another program with a click on your middle mouse button, use the `*` register:

```
"*yy
```

If you selected something in another program and want to put it in Vim, use the `*` register:

```
"*p
```

If you want to yank something in Vim and paste it in another program with Ctrl+v, use the `+` register:

```
"+yy
```

If you copied something in another program with Ctrl+c and want to put it in Vim, use the `+` register:

```
"+p
```

You can synchronize `"*` and `""` (the register used by `y` and `p` by default) with this line in your `vimrc`:

```
set clipboard^=unnamed
```

If you want to synchronize `"+` and `""`:

```
set clipboard^=unnamedplus
```

If you want to synchronize both:

```
set clipboard^=unnamed,unnamedplus
```

This should allow you to yank/put between programs without having to tell Vim what register to use.

Reference:

```
:help registers
:help x11-selection
:help 'clipboard'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.
So I'm trying to remap this "*p-nonse to just p so I can use it properly. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: 1. That's not nonsense. 2. It's explained in my answer.

Comment: Btw. are people really hitting so many keys to paste something?

Sorry, but for me is hitting 3 keys so I can paste something just nonsense.

Comment: Now I get what you are meaning with "synchronize". Thank you very much!

Comment: Back when Vi was created, "people" rarely yanked to and put from other interactive programs because there was no way to run multiple interactive programs in the first place. Even today… yanking to and putting from other programs is not something that should happen *that* often.