# Hiding gvim from the system

Tags: vim

I am on Debian 10 and if I install package `vim` I don't get support for system clipboard like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086958/vim-use-system-clipboard). The only way to get the clipboard support on Debian 10 is to install either `vim-gtk` or `vim-gui-common` packages which both install `gvim`.

And I don't like that, because then I have two editors in my file browser:

---

[image]

---

So I tried to `sudo chmod -x /bin/gvim` but then my system couldn't see `vim` as well! Why is that? So my question is how can I hide `gvim` from my system while not affecting `vim` and keep clipboard functionalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ls -lAF /usr/bin/{g,}vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jul 28  2013 /usr/bin/gvim -> /etc/alternatives/gvim*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 28  2013 /usr/bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim*

$ ls -lAF /etc/alternatives/{g,}vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jul 28  2013 /etc/alternatives/gvim -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jul 28  2013 /etc/alternatives/vim -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk*
```

They point to the same binary. Making `gvim` non-executable automatically makes `vim` non-executable.

So you cannot really "hide" `gvim` but you can remove the symlinks:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/gvim /etc/alternatives/gvim
```

Comment: Thank you. Deleting symbolic links is a nice idea indeed.

Comment: I would urge you to consider [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115591/how-can-i-remove-change-the-open-with-list) instead.